# How can I find all columns A whose subcategories B are all related to the same column C?

Tags: sql, database, relational-algebra

I'm trying to better understand relational algebra and am having trouble solving the following type of question:

Suppose there is a column A (Department), a column B (Employees) and a column C (Managers). How can I find all of the departments who only have one manager for all of their employees? An example is provided below:

```
Department   | Employees   | Managers
-------------+-------------+----------
  A          |  John       |  Bob
  A          |  Sue        |  Sam
  B          |  Jim        |  Don
  B          |  Alex       |  Don
  C          |  Jason      |  Xie
  C          |  Greg       |  Xie
```

In this table, the result I should get are all tuples containing departments B and C because all of their employees are managed by the same person (Don and Xie respectively). Department A however, would not be returned because it's employees have multiple managers.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such problems usually call for a self-join.

Joining the relation onto itself on Department, then filtering out the tuples where the Managers are equal would yield us all the unwanted tuples, which we can just subtract from the original relations.

Here's how I'd do it:

[image: T - \pi_{T.Department, T.Employee, T.Manager} \left( \sigma_{T.Manager \neq T2.Manager \land T.Department = T2.Department}\left(\rho(T, T_2) \times T\right) \right)]

First we make a copy of table T, and call it T2, then take a cross product of T and T2. From the result we select all the rows where T1.Manager /= T2.Manager but T1.Department=T2.Department, yielding us these tuples:

```
T1.Department | T1.Employees| T1.Managers | T2.Managers | T2.Employees | T2.Department
--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------
  A           |  John       |  Bob        | Sam         | Sue          | A
  A           |  Sue        |  Sam        | Bob         | John         | A
```

Departments A and B aren't present because their T1.Manager always equals T2.Manager.

Then we just subtract this result the original set to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your RDBMS supports common table expressions:

```
with C as (
    select department, manager, count(*) as cnt
    from A
    group by department, manager
),
B as (
   select department, count(*) as cnt
   from A group by department
)
select A.*
from A
join C on A.department = C.department
join B on A.department = B.department
where B.cnt = C.cnt;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use aggregate functions such as count (and thus cannot group). I'm trying to solve this question only using relational algebra.